# Why is Ubuntu One synchronization not working?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

Many days ubuntuone synchronisation is not working.
I have Ubuntu 11.04 amd64.

If I do this then:

```
javier@pc-ubuntu:~$ u1sdtool --status 
State: LOCAL_RESCAN
    connection: Not User With Network
    description: doing local rescan
    is_connected: False
    is_error: False
    is_online: False
    queues: WORKING

javier@pc-ubuntu:~$ ps -C ubuntuone-syncdaemon
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
javier@pc-ubuntu:~$ u1sdtool --connect
javier@pc-ubuntu:~$ ps -C ubuntuone-syncdaemon
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3240 ?        00:00:03 ubuntuone-syncd
javier@pc-ubuntu:~$ u1sdtool --status 
State: LOCAL_RESCAN
    connection: Not User With Network
    description: doing local rescan
    is_connected: False
    is_error: False
    is_online: False
    queues: WORKING

javier@pc-ubuntu:~$ ps -C ubuntuone-syncdaemon
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

What can I do?

I have a plan Music Streaming with 20G storage, but I don't happy because very days ubuntuone synchronisation not working for me.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).